# ZUUL Proxy Exception when using Spring Boot/Spring Cloud with Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty, spring-cloud-netflix

We have a few services in our environment for which we use embedded tomcat for development. We did not face any issues with embedded tomcat.

We now want to switch to Liberty Profile.

When we made the switch, we found lots of issues. Basically, we are not getting lots of Caused by: **java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException** as well as **org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server** Error.
Also, loadbalanced RestTemplate is also not working as expected.

We have deployed each of the services in separate Liberty Profile servers. The services listed on http port which is same as that of deployed Liberty Profile server port.

I have added the code I used for ZUUL,Eureka , demo-service and demo-service-client in the github repo,
http://github.com/bsridhar123/spring-cloud-demos

Also, I have shared the **server configuration (server.xml**) for each of the liberty profile servers in the respective service folder in github repo.

Also, the exceptions I see are in the log file,

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsridhar123/spring-cloud-demos/master/demo-service-client-logs.txt

I even tried with registering with ipaddreses, using the property,

**eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true**
 for all services, eureka and zuul.
But, I stil have the same exceptions.

I am not sure if Spring Boot/Spring Cloud Netflix can be used with Liberty Profile Server.

I see none of the exceptions when using embedded tomcat.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, can you please help me on this.

Comment: I am also seeing timeout exception and also internal server exceptions. The complete log with exception stacktrace for ZUUL is at, https://github.com/bsridhar123/spring-cloud-demos/blob/master/logs/zuul-logs.log. Also, exception stacktrace for demo-service-client is at, https://github.com/bsridhar123/spring-cloud-demos/blob/master/logs/demo-service-client-logs.log. Probably it might help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the connection refused errors is for port 8888 which no server.xml listens on.

Another is for http://PC249234.demo.com:54321 -- the zuul server.xml is listening on :54321, who it's impossible to tell if it's actually running on that host at the time the connection attempt is made.

Connection Refused should be relatively easy to debug. Something is either listening, not listening, or overrun by thousands of connections (not likely in a dev env) if you see this TCP error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not sure what could be  the reason when using WLP that some services do not run on the port during certain times, as you say.. I see the service is running fine.  I have never seen any such issues with tomcat.
Can you provide me your suggestions on how to resolve issues on not listening, perhaps it has got to do with WLP server configuration.